# Advanced Custom Fields conflicting with custom plugin when saving custom field

Tags: plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields

I'm writing a plugin for the practice and running into an issue where another plugin, Advanced Custom Fields is conflicting with my code. I have created a custom post type with it's own custom field. My save method works and the custom field data is saved if I disable ACF, however I am getting a validation error that I think comes from the acf plugin when trying to save/publish with the plugin active. See pic for the error message.

So I guess my question is, do I need to check if that plugin is active and use it's functions to handle this and if not do it the normal way, or am I doing something else wrong? Does every plugin that saves custom field data  have to check if this plugin is active and handle it accordingly? That just doesn't seem right to me but this is my first time writing a plugin.

[image: error message]

Here is my save method:

```
public function save_metabox_details() {
        global $post;
        if(current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') && isset($_POST['ipmyskills_nonce'])) {
            $nonce = $_POST['ipmyskills_nonce'];
            if( $nonce && !check_admin_referer( basename(__FILE__), 'ipmyskills_nonce' )) {
                die('Validation error');
            }
            if (isset($_POST['ipmyskills_input'])) {
                $sanitized_value = esc_html( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['ipmyskills_input'] ) );
                update_post_meta($post->ID, 'ipmyskills_input', $sanitized_value);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe try adding your initials to the beginning of your function because if there might be another function with that same name causing the problem. You could try bgs_save_metabox_details.

Comment: No, that didn't do it. it's a class method. Shouldn't be an issue with the name of the method.

Comment: What happens when you change the `die('Validation error');` to `return;` ?

Comment: Nothing, just get the same validation error

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the line with the `update_post_meta()` call? And how are you calling the `save_metabox_details()` - is it hooked to `save_post`? But try an empty function.. `function save_metabox_details() {}` and see if the issue persists - if yes, then the problem is somewhere else..

Comment: Yes I am using the save_post hook. How is it that the problem would be somewhere else when there is no error and the data is saved as expected when the plugin is deactivated?

Comment: I don't know, but there should not be any harm trying my suggestions. And if it doesn't help, you can try debugging the exact errors returned by the ACF validation function. Or post your entire code.. someone might be able to identify the problem source. Btw, you should tag the person you're responding to so that he/she would be notified of your replies.. :)

Comment: And also, I suggest you to use the `$post` object that WordPress can pass to your save function and not using `global $post;`. E.g. `add_action( 'save_post', [ $this, 'save_metabox_details' ], 10, 2 );` and then `function save_metabox_details( $post_id, $post )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I'm a bonehead. I was originally building this with Advanced Custom Fields plugin and doing it in the theme but decided to try and build my first plugin instead. I had created a custom field group and assigned it to the post type with ACF, so that's what was triggering the validation error. Once I deleted the field group everything works as expected.